# How to add new cell at the top of the table view?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a Master and Detail TableViewControllers in my app. If users clicks on + sign on MasterTableViewController then it takes them to DetailTableViewController where they can type/edit "title" and "text". Once they click on back button (<-) it takes them back to MasterTableViewController with a new cell at the bottom of TableView. What changes do I need to do in order to appear newly added cell at the top of TableView ?
Here is the viewWillDisappear method which gets called when they click on back (<-) button.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (self.note) {
    // Update existing Notes
    [self.note setValue:self.titleField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [self.note setValue:self.textView.text forKey:@"text"];
} else {
    // Create a new Notes
    NSManagedObject *newNote = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Note" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [newNote setValue:self.titleField.text forKey:@"title"];
    [newNote setValue:self.textView.text forKey:@"text"];
}

NSError *error = nil;
// Save the object to persistent store
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

//view Did Appear

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // fetch the Note from persistent data store
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Note"];
    self.notes = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

//    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.notes count] inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using `CoreData` to store the newly created objects. On the Master TableViewController, in `viewDidAppear`, you will have to write the code to fetch all the `CoreData` objects into an array and then reload the table data (by calling `[tableView reloadData]`). This will reload the table with latest data.

**EDIT:** Showing latest element on top

1. Add a new attribute to your `CoreData` `Entity`, something like `modifiedOn`, of type `NSDate`.
2. Set this attribute as `[newNote setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"modifiedOn"];`
3. Then you can use this attribute as a `sortDescriptor` in the `fetchRequest` to sort the objects based on *modifiedOn-date.*

Comment: Thanks @Nishant. I am already doing that. I am modifying the question by adding viewDidAppear method. The problem is that new object appears at the bottom and I need it at the top.